# Facebook bot / crawler not identifying itself as a bot (user agent != facebookexternalhit)?

Tags: facebook, bots

I'm advertising on Facebook Ads

I'm getting lots of hits on my server with IPs from Facebook but they are not using the typical user agent "facebookexternalhit". The user agent looks like a legit user.

When you [check the IP](https://www.ip2location.com/demo/173.252.95.13), it's registered under Facebook

So it's hard to detect bots and filter them out. Any idea why they do this and how to detect their IPs?
There's a list of IPs under Facebook Dev area, but that particular IP is not there either

An example:

173.252.95.13 - - [24/Mar/2022:02:19:08 +0000] "GET /in1?utm_source=FB&utm_campaign=C1&fbclid=IwAR0OnUl6Ih4zT-jRhZKnO4Z8xgRcAVN36Z9rNE6WaLtugI0nnnRn4c4Ujyk HTTP/1.1" 200 25186 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.74 Safari/537.36 Edg/99.0.1150.46"

Comment: The page you linked to say it is owned by Digital Ocean.

Comment: @WizKid you are right, sorry, I copy/pasted the wrong line... It's fixed now